# Java Security Ignoring Whitelist

Tags: java, security, firefox

I'm running Oracle 1.8 on Ubuntu 15.04 and having no problems. However, I need too access some java apps from a website as part of a learning module. I am using Firefox 42.0 with the Java PlugIn installed and activated. I click the "Launch" button, the app starts, and I get the pop up telling me that Java Security has blocked the app because it does not have a security file in the .jar. No problem. I open up the control panel and whitelist the domain, the domain/, and the specific app URL. Restart everything and.... Java Security has blocked etc. In the CP the domain shows as whitelisted. And here's what has me talking to myself. After the dialogue closes I can right click the empty app page, click Page Info, and in the Security tab is shows Java as being set to "ALLOW" rather than "Default". So.... Java says the domain is whitelisted. The browser says that Java is set to allow for that domain. And yet... no love. Any ideas?

ETA:  The specific error is that there is no security manifest in the .jar.  According to Oracle's docs, this specific issue is eligible to be addressed by whitelisting.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the form: `[protocol]://[domain]:[port]` in your whitelist? Also, are the applets signed? Also again, are you sure you restarted both browser and any instance of the jvm?

Comment: Dead certain.  I have added http://domain.com/, https://domain.com/, and each specific page URL separately.  The port is only required if it uses an irregular port, which is not the case here.

Comment: So, on port 80. And do you have any control over the applets? Maybe they're not signed or certificates have expired, etc.

Comment: Edited my OP with the specific condition that generates the block.

Comment: According to [Oracle](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml), the white list should work if the applet does not have the `Permission` manifest attribute, but I'm wondering what should happen if it has no manifest at all.

Comment: I wondered that myself but I have to assume that it does have some type of manifest.  I've been able to access the applet on an older Windows machine.

Comment: On an older Windows machine.. with Java < 7u51? My point being, probably the fact that the manifest is missing altogether is the problem. If you have control over the applets I suggest you re-build them with self-signed certificates and all the security paraphernalia, then clear the local cache and restart.

Comment: I have absolutely no control over the applet itself.   And I guess "older" is relative.  It's maybe a year old and running Win 8.